# Animation in class files?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've found myself needing to refer to certain animations in some unknown frame in my classes. What would be the best way to do this? Should I be creating a custum name and specify that all instances of the class should label a certain animation the same thing. For instance:

```
public class CanBeHurt{

    public CanBeHurt() extends MovieClip{
        // constructor code here
    }

    public function hurt():void{
        gotoAndPlay("hurt");
    }
}
```

Any instance of this class would then be forced to label the start of the hurt animation "hurt". Alternatively I could take in strings in the constructor that specify the frame, like so:

```
public class CanBeHurt{
    private var hurtAnimationLabel: String;

    public CanBeHurt(hurtAnimationLabel: String) extends MovieClip{
        this.hurtAnimationLabel = hurtAnimationLabel;
    }

    public function hurt():void{
        gotoAndPlay(hurtAnimationLabel);
    }
}
```

But unfortunately with more complex objects, I already have a bunch of other input arguments for the constructor and with so many animations, I really don't want to add anymore to it. And lastly, the last option I came up with is:

```
public class CanBeHurt{
    private var hurtAnimationLabel: String;

    public CanBeHurt() extends MovieClip{
        this.hurtAnimationLabel = this.currentLabels[0];
    }

    public function hurt():void{
        gotoAndPlay(hurtAnimationLabel);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, with multiple animations, now I'm forced to have my animation labels in a certain order to be able to refer to them properly. Of the 3 methods, I've found the first one to be the most satisfying, but is there a better way?

Comment: As your animation architecture becomes more complex you usually will end up building a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) to keep track of animation logic. Some animations will be interruptible, others wont, sometimes you'll want to trigger a callback when beginning an animation, other times when you complete, sometimes not at all. Some animations loop, some dont. All of that logic is best encapsulated into a dedicated class that is composited into your `MovieClip`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store label names, only if you want the efficient way.

Example:

```
public class CanBeHurt{
    private var label: String;

    public CanBeHurt() extends MovieClip{
        label= "hurtLabel";
    }

    public function hurt():void{
        currentFrameLabel != "hurtLabel" ? gotoAndPlay("hurtLabel") : null;
    }
}
```

You should check the current frame's label and then play the animation to avoid frame stucking. (The animation is always at the first frame)

For games, most of the developers use a function to control the animations, it's the handleAnimation function.

Example:

```
public class Example{
   private var label:String = "someLabel1";

   public Example() extends MovieClip{
      //constructor code here
   }
   private function handleAnimation(){
      if(condition){
         label = "someLabel1";
      }
      if(condition2){
         label = "someLabel2";
      }
      gotoAndPlay(label);
   }
}
```

Comment: Is storing the label name more efficient somehow? Why would I get stuck on the first frame unless I was calling the hurt function repeatedly? And if I was calling it repeatedly, checking the current label isn't going to do anything since the subsequent frames in the animation isn't named "hurtLabel". Why would I need a handleAnimation function when I could just tell it to gotoAndPlay whatever animation I need when needed? And having a handleAnimation function limits all of my animations on one single class.

Comment: You can add +1 layer for the labels. Let's assume that you call the hurt function from an enter_frame event function, then it can be repeatedly called. To make your program clearer and efficient, it's better if you handle the display and the core of the classes seperatedly.

Comment: If I used an ENTER_FRAME event, I would get stuck on the 1st to 2nd frame of the animation because it leaves the frame label on the 2nd frame. And I don't see how it's more efficient if I do it separately rather than all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't extend movieclip for my code. I create some kind of class that accepts a MovieClip in constructor and stores a reference to this and then acts upon it on function calls.

When it comes to label names I usually place them as a static variable in the appropriate class.

This has worked well for me throughout the years :)